# Text size in the app too small

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

**Edit:** *Thanks to everybody that helped. I found a text size library that fixes this problem.*

Since I upgraded to Android Studio 3.0.1,
the text size in my app is on some devices way too small.

What can I do about that?

I put my layout file below

Thanks

And here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/listlayout2"
android:weightSum="1"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/example" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listlayout"
    android:padding="16sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="20sp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/itemicon"
        android:contentDescription="icon"
        android:src="@drawable/settings"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Testtext"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="14sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.2dp"
    app:srcCompat="@color/example"
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is used in a custom navigation drawer item.

Comment: make it larger!

Comment: @Henry Yes, I could do that, but on the emulator and on an Samsung Galaxy S8, it looks good at the moment, so then it would be too big there...

Comment: You did not show us what you actually do. So it is hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: you are doing something wrong. But you didn't show anything, so good lucjk fixing it on your own.

Comment: Use sdp : https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Did you check the text size in the system settings on the devices where it comes out too small?

Comment: @Henry Yeah, I did. It is set to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter code here to set text appearance it displays as per system need

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
android:textSize="30sp"
```

to change the text size and adapt it to your wanted size. 
You can also go for `dp` instead of `sp`

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that and it still was too small on some devices :(

Comment: It shouldn‘t be different on some devices. Is it only wrong on the emulator or on real devices as well?

Comment: @Gamecraftler Would you provide your whole layout file to have a look at it otherwise?

Comment: And is the Problem only on emulator or on real devices?

Comment: Only on some real devices

Answer (score 0):

If you define your textSize in `dp` that won't change your text size throughout the application.

**Edit:** change `sp` to `dp`

Comment: Actually, for text size `sp` is the correct choice.

Comment: Yeah but the guy complains of text being small on some devices. Using dp will help it out there. sp is the first choice mainly.